# Is RAM series Compatible with my MB?

Tags: memory

My motherboard is MSI FM2-A55M-E33 Motherboard. The MSI website says it supports Corsair Corsair [Value Select] Model ID - CMV8GX3M1A1600C- Memory Type- DDR3, frequency 1600 , 512M8DDLG- 1.5V.

The RAM that i purchased matches all the specications above , but does not match the last two digits of model id - My RAM model ID is CMV4GX3M1A1600C11.
Is this RAM series Compatible with my motherboard?

Comment: i checked but it does not list model CMV8GX3M1A1600C11. It says it supports CMV4GX3M1A1600C. The last two digits does not match the RAM model id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your motherboard company's website and check the compatibility list.

[MSI FM2-A55M-E33 Motherboard's compatibility list.](http://us.msi.com/product/mb/FM2-A55M-E33.html#/?div=MEMSupport)

This is a list of all the hardware that has been ACTUALLY tested by the motherboard company. All companies do this for their motherboard.

`i checked but it does not list model` `Is this RAM series Compatible with my motherboard?`

Just because this ram isn't on the list, doesn't mean it's not going to work. As long as the [motherboard specifications](http://us.msi.com/product/mb/FM2-A55M-E33.html#/?div=Basic) (DDR3 1066/1333/1600/1866/2133*(OC)) are the same as your memory, then the likelyhood the ram is going to work is very high, but not a 100%. Which is why they release a compatibility list for each motherboard in the first place, so there is no doubt.